# R ifelse not giving me the right output

Tags: r, if-statement

```
ifelse(BL0304_t2$BAXPFC11==1 & BL0304_t2$BAXPFC21==1 & 
       BL0304_t2$BAXPFC31==1 & BL0304_t2$BAXPFC41==1, 
       BL0304_t2$passcode <-1 , BL0304_t2$passcode <- 2)
```

This should give me "1" for "passcode" when the values for "BAXPFC11", "BAXPFC21", "BAXPFC31", "BAXPFC41" are "1" in and condition and should give me "2" otherwise. But this is giving me "2" in all cases. I am unable to understand what is wrong with the code.

Answer (score 0):

`ifelse` consists of three arguements 1) the logical test, 2) value if true and 3) value if false. You can use this to create a new object. Since you didn't provide any data or desired. This is my guess as to what you want...

```
BL0304_t2$passcode=ifelse(BL0304_t2$BAXPFC11==1 & BL0304_t2$BAXPFC21==1 & 
BL0304_t2$BAXPFC31==1 & BL0304_t2$BAXPFC41==1,1,2)
```

As @Pascal commented, you can also modify the code to minimize characters using `with()`, which would look like:

```
BL0304_t2$passcode=with(BL0304_t2,ifelse(BAXPFC11==1 & BAXPFC21==1 & 
BAXPFC31==1 & BAXPFC41==1,1,2))
```

Comment: Even better: `BL0304_t2$passcode <- with(BL0304_t2, ifelse())`.

Comment: You were naming a new object within the second and third arguments. Please accept the answer if it worked. Thanks!